# Java: Two 'Do while' Loop

Tags: java, loops

I've made a calculator that I have an issue with. I want two 'Do While' loops: One at the end to restart the program entirely, and another if user type anything different than '1 , 2 , 3 or 4'

You can see two variables at the top for that.

Summary: I'd like to have two loops. One for restarting the program, and onefor restarting just after an error to choose the sign.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double result = 0; // multiple variable , switch to choose
    int retryAfterErrorSign = -1;
    int retry = -1;


    System.out.println("Firt number: ");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System. in );
    double nbre1 = sc.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Second number: ");
    double nbre2 = sc.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("1 : Addition");
    System.out.println("2 : Soustraction");
    System.out.println("3 : Multiplication");
    System.out.println("4 : Division");
    retry = sc.nextInt(); //Loop to rechoose number. 

    int sign = sc.nextInt();
    switch (sign) {

        case 1:
            if (sign == 1) result = nbre1 + nbre2;
            System.out.println("The result is " + result);
            break;
        case 2:
            if (sign == 2) result = nbre1 - nbre2;
            System.out.println("The result is " + result);
            break;
        case 3:
            if (sign == 3) result = nbre1 * nbre2;
            System.out.println("The result is " + result);
            break;
        case 4:
            if (sign == 4) result = nbre1 / nbre2;
            System.out.println("The result is " + result);
            break;
        default:
            if (sign != 1 && sign != 2 && sign != 3 && sign != 4) System.out.println("Error , number not recognize");
            System.out.println("Retry (0/1)");
            retryAfterErrorSign = sc.nextInt(); //loop to rechoose sign;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Throw away your if(sign ... lines. The switch..case statement already handles this.

Comment: "... pretty cool proud my self...", "...love you..." - very worth information about your problem.

Comment: @Andremoniy  Relax bro , i'm happy that's all.

Answer (score 2):

What you're talking about is often referred to as a "game loop".  It essentially wraps the entire application in a loop which checks if some terminating condition exists or otherwise just re-starts the whole application.  In Java-like pseudo-code the structure might look something like this:

```
bool keepPlaying = true;
while (keepPlaying) {
    // everything goes in here.
    // if the program should ever end, set keepPlaying to false.
}
```

*Inside* that loop you would have your "game logic" (in this case the "game" is just a calculator, but the concept is the same).  That logic might look something like this:

```
String input = getInputFromUser();
while (!isValid(input)) {
    input = getInputFromUser();
}
// perform the logic on the input
```

So coincidentally there's another loop, but it's entirely separate from and unknown to the overarching "game loop" which drives the whole interface.

Each of these logical abstractions makes for a good boundary to extract a method from the code.  So your entire `main()` method might be *just* the "game loop" and that loop might have only a single statement, `playGame();` or something of that nature.  Then *that* method would contain the application logic, which internally has some loops which themselves call further abstractions (such as `getInputFromUser();` for example);

Answer (score 1):

Do-While-Loop sounds like you're coming from BASIC. In Java, write

```
while(condition) {

}
```

or

```
do {

} while(condition);
```

Note the semantic difference: the first example tests the condition **before** entering the body; the second example tests **after** having executed the body.

Comment: Not really just Started Java 4 days ago haha never programming.

Answer (score 0):

there is some ways, another way is put your code inside a `while(true){... check for a specific condition if true {exit while}... }`

```
while(true){
System.out.println("Firt number: ");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        double nbre1 = sc.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Second number: ");
        double nbre2 = sc.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("1 : Addition");
        System.out.println("2 : Soustraction");
        System.out.println("3 : Multiplication");
        System.out.println("4 : Division");
        retry = sc.nextInt();//Loop to rechoose
        if (retry !=1 && retry !=2 && retry !=3 && retry !=4 ){
           break;
        }
        //....code
}
```

Comment: You mean with a boolean? i'm a beginner also

Comment: yes, of course in most of scenarios whiles check for a condition which it's result is a boolean value.